# Access violation when using Qt with Visual C++ 2008

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I'm trying to use Qt with Visual C++ 2008. I compiled the program below by adding the Qt `include` dir to the Include Files under Options, and adding its `lib` dir to the Library Files list. I've also added the `lib` dir to the `PATH`, and added `QtCore4.lib` to the Additional Dependencies settings in Linker/Input.

I compiled the example program from within Visual Studio, and when I ran it I got the following error, at the line printing the variable `now`.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x104e8dcb in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x203f3f3f.
```

Does anyone know what is the cause if this problem?

```
#include <QtCore/QDate>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string now = QDate::currentDate().toString().toStdString();
    cout << now << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: Added the full content of the error.

Comment: how did you compile it? post complete error..

Comment: Sure, Here's the complete error. I compiled it from within Visual Studio.

Comment: Try `cout << qPrintable( QDate::currentDate().toString() ) << endl;`.  I'm wondering if it's the conversion to string that's the issue.

Comment: Using `qPrintable` seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used the solution from @cmannett85's comment, changing the code to:

```
cout << qPrintable(QDate::currentDate().toString()) << endl;
```